# Gradle | Spring boot dependencies are not excluding

Tags: spring, gradle, log4j, spring-boot, build.gradle

I'm trying to get log4j to work in a project that I'm working on. I added the relevant log4j dependencies in build.gradle and excluded the Spring boot starter logging so it can work.

This worked fine when I used Maven as the build tool, but once I switched to Gradle it's not working at all (excepts the logging from Spring boot starter). Here are the dependencies in my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'){
        exclude module: 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.postgresql:postgresql:9.3-1101-jdbc41')
    compile('org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.10.4')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude module: 'commons-logging'
    }
    providedCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
}
```

But as you can clearly see in the dependency tree the `spring-boot-starter-logging` is still there. I'm guessing that this is the issue why the logging isn't working.

Here's the dependency tree:

```
+--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: -> 1.2.1.RELEASE
|    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-context:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-aop:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    +--- aopalliance:aopalliance:1.0
|    |    |         |    +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-beans:4.1.4.RELEASE (*)
|    |    |         +--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |         \--- org.springframework:spring-expression:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    |              \--- org.springframework:spring-core:4.1.4.RELEASE
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:1.2.1.RELEASE
|    |    |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:1.2.1.RELEASE (*)
|    |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:1.2.1.RELEASE
```

Here's my log4j.properties file

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, fileout, CONSOLE
PID=????
LOG_PATTERN=[%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS}] log4j%X{context} - ${PID} %5p [%t] --- %c{1}: %m%n


# CONSOLE is set to be a ConsoleAppender using a PatternLayout.
log4j.appender.CONSOLE=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CONSOLE.layout.ConversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}

# Log4j configurations for with file appender
log4j.category.org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool=WARN
log4j.category.org.apache.catalina.startup.DigesterFactory=ERROR

log4j.appender.fileout=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.fileout.File=sampleLog.log
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxFileSize=1024KB
log4j.appender.fileout.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.fileout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileout.layout.conversionPattern=${LOG_PATTERN}
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to fix the exclusion of jar file dependency. But the logging is still not working, log4j.properties is also in the WAR distribution under classes.

**UPDATE 02**

It worked issue is with the my IDE (STS)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

All the `spring-boot-starter-*` projects are dependent on `spring-boot-starter` project, which in turn in dependent on `spring-boot-starter-logging`. I was able to remove this dependency by adding the following line in configurations section:

```
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Comment: It worked, spring boot logging dependency has removed, but the logging still not works.

Comment: Is the `sampleLog.log` file generated with no contents or is the file itself is not created?

Comment: On the off chance you're using another module named spring-boot-start-logging, this more explicit syntax also works:
    
    configurations {
      compile.exclude group:"org.springframework.boot", module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
    }

Answer (score 2):

You have excluded the spring-boot-starter-logging module from spring-boot-starter-web, but as you clearly can see from the dependency tree, the module spring-boot-starter-data-jpa also has a dependency to spring-boot-starter-logging, so you also have to exclude it from there (and from all other spring-boot-starter-* dependencies, since all of them depend on spring-boot-starter-logging).

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all logging dependencies using the below code

```
configurations {
    all*.exclude module : 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my gradle / kotlin configuration I was able to exclude it this way:

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude(module = "spring-boot-starter-logging")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this helped:

```
configurations.implementation {
    exclude group: 'org.springframework.boot', module: 'spring-boot-starter-logging'
}
```